# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ConfigParser'

Tags: python-3.x

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kali/w3af/./w3af_gui", line 12, in <module>
    from w3af.core.ui.gui.dependency_check.dependency_check import dependency_check
  File "/home/kali/w3af/w3af/core/ui/gui/dependency_check/dependency_check.py", line 25, in <module>
    from w3af.core.controllers.dependency_check.dependency_check import dependency_check as mdep_check
  File "/home/kali/w3af/w3af/core/controllers/dependency_check/dependency_check.py", line 26, in <module>
    from w3af.core.data.db.startup_cfg import StartUpConfig
  File "/home/kali/w3af/w3af/core/data/db/startup_cfg.py", line 22, in <module>
    import ConfigParser
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
```

someone can help me please?

Comment: best guess is that you want `import configparser` if you are trying to use the module describe by these [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html)

Comment: right, you can do `from configparser import ConfigParser`.

Answer (score 1):

`w3af` isn't supported in Kali Linux rolling. The Python2 dependency has been removed from Kali repositories.

[Does the w3af have python3 version? #17866](https://github.com/andresriancho/w3af/issues/17866)

The [owner say](https://github.com/andresriancho/w3af/issues/17866#issuecomment-495192060):

> No, but we'll have to migrate at some point!

Answer (score 0):

The project `w3af` has been superseded and replaced by `w4af`, which has the same functionality, but support for python3. You can find more information about w4af (which is the direct next version of w3af) here: https://github.com/w4af/w4af , though apparently moderators don't like it when I link to the project.

Comment: The issue with linking to the project will either be "link only answers" (which can be avoided by adding a bit of explanatory text... I think this answer has enough) or the suspicion that you're promoting your own project (which just needs disclosure, if it is your project)

Comment: Somehow, when I answered a question explaining that it was my project, and linking to the project, that also got deleted by mods. I don't know what a Stackoverflow-friendly way of communicating the information would be. "The code you are trying to run has thousands of blocking issues because it is unmaintained; in this other project I have spent a year resolving those issues - here is the other project..."